# Show GDScript Warnings when running from command line

Tags: command-line-interface, warnings, godot, gdscript

I'm running some GDScript code from the command line, using the simple command

```
godot .
```

from my project directory.

If something goes wrong, such as trying to access a nonexistent node, then that error gets printed to my command line's output stream. However, the Godot editor also shows some less severe warnings (things like "integer division warning" or "this local variable shadows another variable"), and *those* warnings don't get shown at all when running from the command line.

[image: Example of warning messages in the Godot editor]

How can I instruct the `godot` application to, from the command line, dump any GDScript warnings to the console as well? The usual suspects of `-Wall` and `-Wextra` (which work for C++, for instance) have failed me, and I don't see anything about GDScript warnings on the [command line documentation page](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/editor/command_line_tutorial.html).

Example script that *should* show a "shadowing variable" warning but does not, when run from the command line.

```
class Symbol extends Reference:
    func _init(contents):
        self.contents = contents
    var contents
```

Running Godot 3.5 on Fedora 31, if that matters.